# DXF Export contains additional layer 2216

Tags: qgis, autocad, cad

I am exporting my QGIS layers using this (see image below):
[image]

I am using QGIS 2.8.0 and CAD 2013. The layers are correctly showing when i open my dxf file in CAD but surprisingly same operation is working correctly on another system (PC).

It is creating additional layer with name 2216 and my all layer inside that layer while my all layers is also present. What i am doing wrong? Do i require additional settings?

Comment: Can you upload the DXF for a test. What is this for a CAD program at which it does not work.

Comment: sorry i can't do it . CAD 2013

Comment: Can you install a newer QGIS version? There have been many improvements related to DXF since 2.8